# How to pass an api key as part of url in my ember app

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember app that is consuming an API. My API requires an API key be sent in the URL like...

```
myJunk.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=d26da3938adc5f3c8604256194c18501
```

Here is the ember code I'm trying to get to work...

```
App.Person = Ember.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.attr()
});

App.Person.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();
App.Person.url = "http://myJunk.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=d26da3938adc5f3c8604256194c18501";
App.Person.collectionKey = "shots";
```

The issue I'm having is that '.json' is being appended to the URL. Here is the error I get in chrome...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myJunk.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=d26da3938adc5f3c8604256194c18501.json.
```

Looks like this is a know [issue](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/300)...

What is the right way to do this in ember?

Comment: The issue that you pointed is fixed, [this](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/pull/301) is the PR with the fix. Maybe you're using an older version of ember-model which doesn't have this fix. Can you update to a lastest version, and confirm if the problem still happens?

Comment: marcio why did you not put this in the answer section?

Comment: I am using the latest starter kit at https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit. Should the fix be in this build? I can't tell from the bug/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the fix has not made it to the release version yet. See github comment...

https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/300

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my `ApplicationAdapter` as follows:

```
ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) {
    if(window.ENV.api_key) {
        if(hash === undefined) {
            hash = {data: {api_key: window.ENV.api_key}};
        } else {
            if(hash.data) {
                hash.data.api_key = window.ENV.api_key;
            } else {
                hash.data = {api_key: window.ENV.api_key};
            }
        }
    } else {
        Ember.Logger.debug('no api key');
    }
    return this._super(url, type, hash);
}
```

With the current user's API key stored in `ENV.api_key`. This way it is inserted into all requests, POST or GET.